# How to create JOIN tables in create action and assign relevant ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For a room reservation I would like to include options for the room.

The options and its join table reservation_options seem to be inserted correctly into my params, but I am not able to properly assign the option_quantity value of the join table. It gives me the error message ```no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer ``

As the options are dynamically generated in the form as they are dependent on the selected room_type, I tried building them in the create action. However I am not able to iterate over the params and build them (see create action for my attempt).

**Params**

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7QJHgdYW8ubKiNpLPET7tYzGNyqmp69dafo8NDaAUBf2PL3CI9XhKmd/am2Mo/A93EFZQByltwe2e4wepMXdqw==", "reservation"=>{"rooms"=>{"room_type"=>"185"}, "arrival"=>"2019-10-25", "departure"=>"2019-10-26", "room_id"=>"266", "reservation_contact_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "street"=>"street", "street_number"=>"", "zipcode"=>"4049", "city"=>"Gent", "country"=>"", "email"=>"john@hotmail.com", "phone"=>""}, "payment"=>"not paid"}, "reservation_options_attributes"=>[{"option_id"=>"109", "option_quantity"=>"1"}, {"option_id"=>"110", "option_quantity"=>"1"}], "commit"=>"Save & proceed to additional options", "hotel_id"=>"109"}
```

**Models**

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :options, through: :reservation_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation_options
end

class ReservationOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :reservation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_type
  has_many :reservation_options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_options
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Reservation controller**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  # skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @age_tables = @hotel.age_tables

    @reservation.build_reservation_contact
    @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
    @all_options = @hotel.options
    @rooms = []
    @options = []
    @extra_guests = []

    if params[:room_type].present?
      @rooms = Room.find(params[:room_type]).rooms
      @options = Room.find(params[:room_type]).options
      @extra_guests = Room.find(params[:room_type]).extra_guests
    end
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
        render json: {rooms: @rooms, options: @options, extra_guests: @extra_guests}
      }
        format.js
      end
    end

    authorize @reservation
  end

  def create
    def create
    @user = current_user
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    @reservation.hotel = @hotel
    authorize @reservation
    if @reservation.save
      params[:reservation_options_attributes].each do |reservation_option|
        if @option = Option.find_by(id: reservation_option[:option_id])
          @reservation.options << @option
          # output 1 for reservation_option

          reservation_option = @reservation.reservation_options.where(option: @option)
          # output 2 for reservation_option

          reservation_option.update(option_quantity: reservation_option[:option_quantity])
          # Error message

        end
      end

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
      render 'new'
    end
  end
private
  def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:room_id, :arrival, :departure, :payment, :reservation_contact_id, option_ids:[],
      reservation_contact_attributes: [:id, :first_name,
      :last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :zipcode, :city, :street, :street_number,
      :email, :phone, :date_of_birth, :country, :company, :gender, :vat_number],
        rooms_attributes: [:id,:name, :room_type_id,
          room_types_attributes: [:id, :name]],
      reservation_options_attributes: [:id, :option_id, :option_quantity, :_destroy,
        options_attributes: [:id, :name, :room_type_id, :description,
          room_types_attributes:[:id, :name]]],
      reservation_extra_guests_attributes: [:id, :extra_guest_id, :extra_guest_quantity, :_destroy,
        extra_guests_attributes: [:id, :name, :room_type_id, :age_table_id,
          room_types_attributes:[:id, :name]]])
  end
end
```

output 1 for reservation_option

```
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"option_id"=>"110", "option_quantity"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

output 2 for reservation_option

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<ReservationOption id: 62, option_id: 110, reservation_id: 142, option_quantity: nil, created_at: "2019-10-25 12:27:45", updated_at: "2019-10-25 12:27:45">]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do what you're looking for:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = @hotel.reservations.new(reservation_params)
    if @reservation.save
      params[:reservation_options_attributes].each do |reservation_option|
        if @option = Option.find_by(id: reservation_option[:option_id])
          @reservation.options << @option
          reservation_option = @reservation.reservation_options.where(option: @option)
          reservation_option.update(option_quantity: reservation_option[:option_quantity])
        end
      end
      authorize @reservation
      redirect_to hotel_path(@hotel)
    else
      @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

This assumes, naturally, that `Reservation belongs_to :hotel`, which you don't currently show in your `Reservation` model. And, also, that `Hotel has_many :reservations`.

This also assumes that your `ReservationOption` model has a `option_quantity` attribute. That seems like a natural place to have such a thing.

Comment: Thank you (again). I can now generate the reservation_options and options, up to the point of assigning the option_quantity (e.g. ```reservation_option.update(quantity: reservation_option[:option_quantity])```). Here I get the error  ```no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer```

Comment: FYI. I updated my question with the latest developments.

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave me 90% of the solution. In the end I solved it by identifying ```@option_quantity = reservation_option[:option_quantity] ``` and pushing it this way instead ```reservation_option.update(option_quantity: @option_quantity) ```